# Bootstrap 4 Responsive Amin panel Design

Tags: css, angular, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, angular-bootstrap

I am trying to create a responsive admin panel

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light static-top">
  <a [routerLink]="['/']"><img src="../../../assets/img/monash-logo-mono@2x.png" class="logo" /></a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" (click)="toggle()" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav"
    aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="navbar-light bg-light collapse navbar-collapse" [ngClass]="{'show': !isCollapsed}" id="navbarNav">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
      <div>
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input name="s" id="s" type="text" class="search-query form-control" autocomplete="off"
              placeholder="Search...">
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<main class="content">
  <div class="row" style="height: 100%;">
    <div class="col-3" style="background: blue;">
      <nav class="container">
        <div class="nav flex-column nav-pills" id="v-pills-tab" role="tablist" aria-orientation="vertical">
          <a class="nav-link active" id="v-pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-home" role="tab"
            aria-controls="v-pills-home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
          <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-profile-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-profile" role="tab"
            aria-controls="v-pills-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
          <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-messages-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-messages" role="tab"
            aria-controls="v-pills-messages" aria-selected="false">Messages</a>
          <a class="nav-link" id="v-pills-settings-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-settings" role="tab"
            aria-controls="v-pills-settings" aria-selected="false">Settings</a>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="col-9">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
<!-- TODO: footer -->
```

[image]

Trying to create a panel something like this 
[image]

When switch to the small screen the drawer should be overlap with an icon button to click

[image]

Comment: https://codepen.io/wideckop/pen/ZOgOPq try this.

Comment: @RavinderKumar : You should put this as an answer mate. Cheers.

Comment: @RavinderKumar  You design is perfect for me. Can you please have with nav bar as on the larger screen as well as in the short screen.

Comment: Please, can you let me know how can we add nab bar header in a big screen as well as on a small screen?